# use angular2 component property at init jquery function

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am developing web app by using angular2. i am also using jquery auto complete. i make request to remote server and get completion data but server address is hardcoded in auto complete function. i tried to use component property but i could not pass value as parameter to jquery init function.

```
ngOninit() {
   this.initJquery();
 }
 private initJQuery() {
    setTimeout(() => {

        $(() => { 
            $("#city-area").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "***how to use component value here?***",
                      ...
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

            };
        });
    }, 0); 
}
```

how can i use component value in jquery function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's some funky code. Anyways, you should never use the `function` keyword inside a TypeScript class. This will mess up the `this` context. Always use the arrow function notation:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.initJquery();
}

private initJQuery() {    
  $("#city-area").autocomplete({
     source: (request, response) => {
        $.ajax({ 
           url: this.url
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = (ul, item) => {}; 
  });
}
```

Comment: if you use `function`, yes.. then it does. Not if you use the `() => {}` notation. Can you add where you use this code inside the class?

Comment: My answer remains the same, use the arrow notation, and not `function`

Comment: Told you it would :D

Comment: yes :) and why did you tell that it is funky? i had to use jquery autocomplete code. is there another way to accomplish using jquery with angular2?

Comment: I've updated my answer a little. The funky parts were, the `setTimeout`, the `$({})` wrapper. Those are unnecessary if you use the `ngAfterViewInit` hook. Besides that, I personally discourage using `jQuery` with angular, because they are so different and it gets confusing fast. There are angular2 autocomplete libraries out there. But, I do understand if you want to use jquery, personal preferences differ :). The last funky part is the access of the private property `_renderItem` and how you assign a function to it

Comment: $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<div class='trn-    autocomplete'><div class='trn-autocomplete-location'><i class='fa fa-bed hotel'></i> " + `${item.countryName} - ${item.regionName || ''} -${item.destinationName}` + "</div></div>").appendTo(ul);